# Office 2013 handling of (Xe)LaTex PDFs?

Tags: conversion, msword

I just read that Office 2013 now includes PDF import and editing functionality, so that it converts the PDF automatically into a format that could be edited and saved as a .doc. I was wondering whether anyone has had a chance to play with this, and if so how well it handles academic papers written in Latex/Xelatex, especially with respect to footnotes, multiple languages or fonts, and citations/references (and math, though this isn't as important to me personally). It would be nice to get some sense of how well it works before considering upgrading to the 2013 suite, since I'm sure that will come with its own set of new UI, etc. headaches.

Comment: This look borderline for on-topic to me: I see the link to TeX, but it's essentially down to Word what happens.

Comment: @JosephWright May be if the question is rephrased. In its core, it links to the never-ending story: _How to convert LaTeX docs to Word_. If Word 2013 convert well, maybe Word will be the ultimate solution (which I doubt, since Word 2007 is not even able to convert all Word 2003 docs to .docx, not mine at least).

Comment: This is a comment to be read on 2017: *Open a PDF file in Word put a dot or delete one letter, save it. It will break the kerning of the whole PDF file.*

Comment: @JosephWright - I think it is on-topic because it asks about a fairly specific case of use - converting PDF documents which contain certain features, as typically produced by Latex, via Office 2013. It is a "conversion" question which is why I tagged it that way. The reason I asked is that I've been unable to find any examples of people testing this PDF reading capability using an academic document produced using Latex. I've only seen a couple examples of very different types of files being converted (e.g. instruction manuals).

Comment: I guess, it won't work properly. They would need to guess the producer of the pdf and design specific pdf import for each producer, as each producer produces quiet different pdf structure.

Comment: I have found a couple of suggestive pages, though no systematic comparison. This (http://www.planetpdf.com/enterprise/article.asp?ContentID=PDF_Reflow_in_Microsoft_Word_2012_Is_it_any_good) is the only detailed thing I've found, though here's a screenshot of a scientific paper: http://edge.alluremedia.com.au/m/l/2012/08/Word2013PDF.jpg. The reason I asked here was that I thought someone using TeX might have tried a systematic comparison - I can't imagine a better place to ask this question.

Comment: If it is any indicative of the present technology on PDF-to-`.docx` conversion, the "save as MS Word" function of Adobe Acrobat X Pro (not the Reader) is at best disappointing. Footnote texts are converted as ordinary texts with smaller font size. That means, after the conversion, if you add more than one line of text before a footnote, it's going to get pushed to the top of the next page. Math texts are a also disaster. Personally I wouldn't put too much faith on Word 2013, though I'm not as pessimistic as @percusse either ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty impressed of the result actually and for reference, footnote and endnote it does a good job. Although footnote aren't translate as Word footnote. What the converter actually does to preserve the aspect of the paper is adding tabulation and other format characters. Also it does not handle accents for I tried with a report I wrote in French (yeah I'm a french canadian) and every accent were added in front of the letter in this manner " `e " a simple search and replace should do the job but with other small corrections it starts to become a lot, especially if you want to add large part of text. So it might not be as good as pdf directly compiled from LaTeX, but if you have to submit a report to your employer because the business only work with word it is a good way to translate PDF to `.doc` although it might need small change in the layout of the document (pagebreak need to be reinserted).

PS: the summary will not update you have to change mannually the page number, but again  if you do change so again it's more to create a `.doc` version of your document when `.doc` are needed.

PPS: I quite like Word 2013 it can be useful by adding shortcuts were needed and not adding more button in the Ui bar it's more efficient than other versions, it's handling more thing without having to search for the correct button for the circumstance, i.e. converting a PDF file is simply done by openning it with the open button.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on how it handles other common features, e.g. internal and external hyperlinks, XMP metadata, embedded files, character protrusion and expansion.
Also I’d like to know if the paragraphs stay intact.

Comment: I will  try for hyperlink, but for embedded files it seems that the converter insert everything it cannot translate as text to an image. I tried with image, table and equation and every time I got an image in the '.doc'. Althougth sometimes with in-text equation you have a text version but if the symbols are somewhat special you get an image in the text. Also captions are no more captions, but text put in place with some kind of layout, they are not linked to the image. pagebreak are kept but the text use less page, so they need to be moved.